# Grunt not being added to Environment Variables Path

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-8, gruntjs, npm

I installed the Grunt cli with the following command?

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

Then I created the package.json and the Grunfile.js and run

`npm install -S grunt`

But `grunt` is not known by Windows. It says *"´grunt´ is not recognized as an internal or external command"*.

Typing `path` on console, doesn't show Grunt, and `where grunt` also fails.

Did everything as Administrator on a Windows 8 machine.

What is wrong with this installation?

obs: and where is it installed?

Comment: what is the output of `npm ls -g --depth=0`?

Comment: @JesseFulton `empty`